# Clang cannot use inherited constexpr constructors in members of class templates

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, constexpr

We encountered a surprising compilation error: turning a class into a class template, a compilation error occurred in on of its member function. The error was complaining about a `constexpr` local variable of unaffected type not being initialized by a constant expression.

(The error with types edited out, posted here for search-ability of the error)

```
constexpr variable 'localVar' must be initialized by a constant expression
        constexpr Derived localVar{...};                                             
note: constructor inherited from base class 'Base' cannot be used in a constant expression; derived class cannot be implicitly initialized
```

This error did not occur on our Windows environment, but on Apple clang. It can be reduced to the [minimal example also found on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Zaisp_):

```
struct Base
{
    constexpr Base(int, double)
    {}
};

struct Derived : public Base
{
    // Inherit parent ctor(s)
    using Base::Base;
};

// Commenting out the following line clang also compiles
template <class>
struct X
{
    void memFun()
    {
        // The following line is fine.
        const Derived derived{0, 3.0};

        // This line is fine too
        constexpr Base base{0, 2.0};

        // The following line produces an error.
        constexpr Derived c_derived{0, 3.0};
    }
};
```

Since turning `X` into a non-templated class fixes everything, the situation feels worrying.

- Is this code legal? (i.e. which compiler is right here?)
- Are there any reasons not to write such code? Or workarounds to make this work on all major platforms?

---

There is also a [bug thread for GCC](https://www.mail-archive.com/search?l=gcc-bugs@gcc.gnu.org&q=subject:%22%5C%5BBug%20c%5C%2B%5C%2B%5C%2F78022%5C%5D%20constexpr%20int%20template%20rejected%20unless%20constructor%20is%20used%20before%20hand%22&o=newest&f=1) treating of a very similar (identical?) problem.

Comment: I would say clang bug...

Comment: As work around, you might write the inherited constructor yourself :/ [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/2UQHM4)

Comment: Thank you @Jarod42 for your suggestion. Sadly it would be too detrimental to the actual codebase: the inheritance runs on several levels, and there are several constexpr ctors on each class (not necessarily as trivial as in this minimal example).